# How do I reinstall Pulseaudio in 16.04?

Tags: pulseaudio, steam, reinstall

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 on my Chromebook through Crouton.  I am trying to get the Steam game Saint's Row 2 to run.  I am experiencing a crash to Desktop every time I start the game at one of the intro screens.  On the Linux Gaming Reddit several users were also having this issue, they said that reinstalling Pulseaudio fixed the problem for them.  Apparently there is some kind of a missing file that the game needs and reinstalling Pulseaudio creates that file.  I tried the command `sudo apt-get --reinstall pulseaudio` however that yielded an invalid command response.  I have tried googling around and have seen a few other threads on AskUbuntu of users reinstalling Pulseaudio however I am not sure if I should go about the methods listed for them as it seems like some of them were having audio issues to begin with.  Things are working great for me, I just need a reinstall to get that file.  How do I do this without disrupting any of my current settings.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `install` command, just do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the correct command.  Unfortunately the game still does not work but Pulseaudio was reinstalled.

Comment: @undyinglight, Steam is beyond my limits, it uses proton engine to run Windows games. However, if you used have wine, you could have enabled virtual desktop to run it.

Comment: The specific game Saint's Row 2 I am trying to run is actually a native Linux game.  As I have googled around this error of crashing on the start up screen seems to effect Windows and Linux users.  I do think that reinstalling Pulseaudio will work for most users.  In my scenario I think I am running into issues as I have the game installed in a location that is not chosen by Steam by default.  I changed the install directory to my SD card as my Hard Drive is small on my Chromebook.  I am guessing that it did not know to put the new file in SD card folder.

Comment: @undyinglight, I did not find anything from the Internet to help you fix the the problem. My advice for you: do not waste your time playing games. BTW, sorry for being not helpful, I am not expert in these fields.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help you did provide. Today I learned how to reinstall Pulseaudio, something that I did not know how to do yesterday. Playing games can be a waste of time but it is not necessarily so I would argue. They can be a good source of entertainment. Personally they help me with PTSD. To each there own though! My regards

Answer (score 0):

Below commands would do it for you.
`sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio`
`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`